# React: Child Component Does Not Rerender When Submitting Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-router-dom

I am new in React and I will appreaciate much any help. I am using create-react-app, react-router-dom and express server. When I try to submit a comment to a blog post (child component called Details), it gets stored in the database, however the component does not seem to update and i do not see the new comment.As a result, I can see the new comment only after i refresh the page but not on form submit. I guess I am not setting componentDidUpdate properly but I do not have a clue how to do it, so i can see the comment immediately.

Here is my App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userId: null,
      username: null,
      isAdmin: false,
      isAuthed: false,
      jwtoken: null,
      posts: [],
      filtered: [],
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  static authService = new AuthService();
  static postService = new PostService();
  static commentService = new CommentService();

  componentDidMount() {

    const isAdmin = localStorage.getItem('isAdmin') === "true"
    const isAuthed = !!localStorage.getItem('username');

    if (isAuthed) {
      this.setState({
        userId: localStorage.getItem('userId'),
        username: localStorage.getItem('username'),
        isAdmin,
        isAuthed,
      })
    }
    this.getPosts()

  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, posts) {
    if (prevState === this.state) {
      this.getPosts()
    }
  }


  handleChange(e, data) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }     

  handleCommentSubmit(e, data) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.reset();
    App.commentService.createComment(data)
      .then(body => {
        this.getposts()
        if (!body.errors) {
          toast.success(body.message);
        }
        else {
          toast.error(body.message);
        }
      }
      )
      .catch(error => console.error(error));

  }

  getPosts() {
    App.postService.getPost()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          posts: data.posts.length? data.posts : []
        });
      }
      )
      .catch(e => this.setState({ e }))
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Header username={this.state.username} isAdmin={this.state.isAdmin} isAuthed={this.state.isAuthed} logout={this.logout.bind(this)} />

        <Switch>

          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (
            <Home
              posts={this.state.posts}
              handleSearchSubmit={this.handleSearchSubmit.bind(this)}
              handleChange={this.handleSearchChange.bind(this)}
              {...props} />
          )} />

          <Route path="/posts/:id" render={(props) =>
            <Details handleSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit.bind(this)}
              isAdmin={this.state.isAdmin}
              isAuthed={this.state.isAuthed}
              posts={this.state.posts}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              {...props} />} />



        </Switch>

        <Footer posts={this.state.posts} formatDate={this.formatDate} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Here is my Details.js:

```
class Details extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: null,
      comment: null
    }
    this.handleChange = props.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { posts, match } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      post: posts.length
        ? posts.find(p => p._id === match.params.id)
        : null,
      userId: localStorage.getItem('userId')
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { posts, match, isAuthed } = this.props;

    if (JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(this.props)) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      post: posts.length
        ? posts.find(p => p._id === match.params.id)
        : null
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;
    const { isAdmin, isAuthed } = this.props;

    if (!post) {
      return <span>Loading post ...</span>;
    }

    return (
      <section className="site-section py-lg">

           <form onSubmit={(e)=> this.props.handleSubmit(e, this.state)} className="p-5 bg-light">

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="message" onChange={this.handleChange} cols={30} rows={10} className="form-control" defaultValue={ ""} />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                 <input type="submit" defaultValue="Post Comment" className="btn btn-primary" />
              </div>
           </form>}
       </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Details;
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a mistake that will be done by any new React developer. Just remember one thing that:-

> UI is a function of state

So your UI will only be updated if your state is update.

After submitting a comment don't fetch all your comments again, just `concat` your new comment to current state and you will see your comment as soon as you submit it successfully

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide an example because I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I am trying to change the state in handleCommentSubmit method with this.getPosts() function. It should refresh all posts with the added comment, but the changes are not applied.

Comment: @Badan I just noticed one thing. Can you explain to me why you are using `componentDidUpdate` in your `App.js`  and what it is doing?

Comment: I am fetching all the articles in App.js and i am passing all the articles as props to the child components with react-router-dom. GetAllPosts function fetches data (the articles) from the api.

Comment: Can you try with doing condition opposite in your `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Hmm, now it is working but it refreshes the whole page (shows the "loading" span, so I think there should be a better implementation from user experience perspective,